# How to alias a directory change in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, alias

Why does `Set-Alias foo "cd C:\foo\bar\xyz\asdf\etc"` not work?

> foo
>
> -> invalid format

How to do this correctly?

Comment: you can't alias this, but you can write a function: `function foo { cd "C:\users" }`

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, You cannot alias a cmdlet-and-a-variable into an alias name.
I mean **it is valid** if you write `Set-Alias foo cd`
but
it is **not valid** to write `Set-Alias foo cd C:\Users`
See the example image below for better understanding.
[image]

The error clearly says

> Cannot resolve alias 'foo' because it refers to term 'cd C:\Users' which is **not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program or script file**

So `Set-Alias` command is expecting only four of the following to be aliased

1. cmdlet
2. function
3. operable program
4. script file.

The path `C:\Users` does not qualify as one.
**You can write a script file (*.ps1) and get this done through alias**

Use the `get-alias` command to see the list of aliases that have been set in the system.
Use `Remove-item` command to reset the alias that have been set.
[Reference](http://ss64.com/ps/set-alias.html)

Answer (score 1):

make a function inside profile.ps1 (function name uppercase)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914589/how-to-create-permanent-powershell-aliases

eg. 
function Mesa{ 
cd $home\Desktop\
 }